# Trim audio file and get the part between silence

Tags: linux, audio, terminal, speech, sox

My goal is to get the parts of audio file that contains non-noise sounds by using SoX. I have read the effects of SoX and found `noisered` and `silence` which I consider helpful. The problem is that I have not found command that can trim the audio file based on the silent pauses in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for can be achieved with a `sox silence` command. It allows you to remove the silence from any part of the audio given a threshold, durations above it, etc.

For a detailed manual please refer to the [**sox webpage**](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html), the silence section is very well written.

---

If you want to split at silence and not to "squeeze" everything together, then you might want to try something like:

```
sox input.wav slice.wav silence 1 1.0 2% 1 3.0 2% : newfile : restart
```

Parameters are:

`input.wav` - input audio file

`slice.wav` - output audio files name (numbers will be appended to each slice)

`silence` - effect name

`1 1.0 2%` - above_periods, duration, threshold

`1 3.0 2%` - below_periods, duration, threshold

Comment: but does silence trim big audio file into small, I mean if we have big audio file which contains "I use SoX", does silence trim this audio file into small ones: "I"; "use"; "SoX"

Comment: By default it does not split the audio file, you must use a bit of *sox magic*. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I dont know if it is right to ask you here, but are you free for a few minutes to explain to me how this is working.

Comment: I guess you will have to go through the sox manual entry for *silence* that I provided you with - all parameters are explained over there.